# Linq query change from List<string> to List<T> where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that works when it I had a list of a single value now that I change to having a List that has several properties I need to change the where clause

So this works:

```
List<string> etchList = new List<string>();
etchList.Add("24");

var etchVect = (from vio in AddPlas
              where etchList.Any(v => vio.Key.Formatted.Equals(v))
              let firstOrDefault = vio.Shapes.FirstOrDefault()
              where firstOrDefault != null
              select new
              {
                  EtchVectors = firstOrDefault.Formatted
              }).ToList();
```

However I have a new hard coded list (which will represent incoming data:

```
List<ExcelViolations> excelViolations = new List<ExcelViolations>();

        excelViolations.Add(new ExcelViolations
        {
            VioID = 24,
            RuleType = "SPACING",
            VioType = "Line-Line",
            XCoordinate = 6132,
            YCoordinate = 10031.46
        });
```

So the NEW Linq query looks like this, but is obviously will not work as 
AddPlas is a List and so using this other list of excelviolations, I wish to have it do where on each one of the properties in the excelviolations list

```
var etchVect = (from vio in AddPlas
              where excelViolations.Any(vioId => vio.Key.Formatted.Equals(vioId))
              let firstOrDefault = vio.Shapes.FirstOrDefault()
              select new
              {
                  EtchVectors = firstOrDefault.Formatted
              }).ToList();
```

Now, since this is a list within a list, I would like to do something like add in each of the properties
so for example:

```
 where excelViolations.VioID.Any(vioId => vio.Key.Formatted.Equals(vioId))
```

However that is not possible,  but you see that I'm trying to access the property of VioID  that is in the excelViolations and match it to the Key which is in vio list

Comment: What do you mean by "do where on each one of the properties"? Do you still only have the `VioID` to match against? What do you want to compare with the other properties?

Comment: So in SQL I am use to using a Where VioID=24  AND RuleType = "Spacing" ,   thus I want to use the where clause to match each one of the properties in my list.

Comment: But you haven't shown us where you expect us to get "Spacing" from. You're still using `from vio in AddPlas` - where is `RuleType` within that?

Comment: yes, that is where i'm stuck,  : where excelViolations.Any(vioId => vio.Key.Formatted.Equals(vioId))    I know that previously before I had the new list of excelViolations , I had only etchList  which I gather that it only contains one value "24"  thus it works.   Now that I'm wanting to switch this List<string> out for List<ExcelViolations>  I was stuck

Comment: Well you need to work out your requirements first. This isn't a coding issue yet - if you don't know where the data is coming from, I don't see how we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line

```
where excelViolations.Any(vioId => vio.Key.Formatted.Equals(vioId))
```

to

```
where excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.Key.Formatted.Equals(excelVio.VioID))
```

then i thought it will works

Comment: Sweet, that works!   oh,  I need to excelVio.VioID to a string (currently an int)  I temporary changed the property of VioID from an int to string to get it to work

Comment: where excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.Key.Formatted.Equals(excelVio.VioID.ToString()))   that works  thanks again